# Dispatch action on Auth0's lock.on('authenticated') event

Tags: authentication, reactjs, redux, auth0

I want to implement the new Auth0 Lock 10 in my React/Redux app.

I've checked on the internet, but nothing matches my question. There's a tutorial [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/redux-authentication-auth0/), but it uses the Popup mode instead of the Redirect (default now) mode. Another [one](https://auth0.com/forum/t/having-trouble-with-login-following-the-react-guide/3084) parses the url, which is useless in Lock 10.

Here's the flow:

- The Auth0Lock gets instantiated when my app starts
- When the user clicks on the login button, it shows the Lock widget (`lock.show()`) and dispatches LOGIN_REQUEST
- The lock does its authentication on auth0.com (redirects out of my localhost)
- Redirect back to my localhost after successful login, the Auth0Lock get instantiated again
- I wait for an `lock.on('authenticated')` event to dispatch LOGIN_SUCCESS

And here is my actions/index.js code:

```
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock'

export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST'
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'
export const LOGIN_ERROR = 'LOGIN_ERROR'

function loginRequest() {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST
  }
}

function loginSuccess(profile) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    profile
  }
}

function loginError(error) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_ERROR,
    error
  }
}

// import AuthService to deal with all the actions related to auth
const lock = new Auth0Lock('secret', 'secret', {
  auth: {
    redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    responseType: 'token'
  }
})

lock.on('authenticated', authResult => {
  console.log('Im authenticated')
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch(loginSuccess({}))
  }
})

lock.on('authorization_error', error => {
  return dispatch => dispatch(loginError(error))
})


export function login() {
  lock.show()
  return dispatch => {return dispatch(loginRequest())}
}
```

Now when I click on the login button, redux logger shows me LOGIN_REQUEST action dispatched, I see the lock widget, I can login, it redirects to auth0.com then back to my `localhost:3000/callback` with a pretty token. Everything is fine, I see the `Im authenticated` message in my console, but redux logger doesn't show me that the LOGIN_SUCCESS action has been dispatched.

I'm new to Redux, and I guess I'm missing one thing, but I cannot get grab of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally put in inside actions.js, I created a new function called `checkLogin()`

```
// actions.js

const authService = new AuthService(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN)

// Listen to authenticated event from AuthService and get the profile of the user
// Done on every page startup
export function checkLogin() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    // Add callback for lock's `authenticated` event
    authService.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
      authService.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
        if (error)
          return dispatch(loginError(error))
        AuthService.setToken(authResult.idToken) // static method
        AuthService.setProfile(profile) // static method
        return dispatch(loginSuccess(profile))
      })
    })
    // Add callback for lock's `authorization_error` event
    authService.lock.on('authorization_error', (error) => dispatch(loginError(error)))
  }
}
```

And in the constructor of my `App` component, I call it

```
import React from 'react'
import HeaderContainer from '../../containers/HeaderContainer'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.checkLogin() // check is Auth0 lock is authenticating after login callback
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <HeaderContainer />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  checkLogin: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default App
```

See here for full source code: https://github.com/amaurymartiny/react-redux-auth0-kit

Answer (score 1):

My Reactjs knowledge is limited, but this was starting to be to long for a comment...

Should you not be calling `store.dispatch(...)` from the lock events?

Having those events return a function won't do anything unless someone invokes the function that is returned and to my knowledge Lock does not do anything with the return value of the callback function you pass as an event handler.

Comment: Alright. But in my case, I put actions inside a separate actions.js file, and if I understand correctly, invoking the store from that file is an anti-pattern. In that case, should I rather initialize `const lock = new Auth0Lock(...)` inside actions.js, or in a component like the App component?

Comment: That's where my lack of React knowledge won't allow me to voice any opinion.

Comment: I finally did it in actions.js, see here for the code: https://github.com/amaurymartiny/react-redux-auth0-kit/blob/master/src/actions/auth.js

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is auth0 redirects the browser window to the login authority (auth0 itself, Facebook, Google, etc.) then redirects you back to your app, which reloads your page, essentially wiping out all state. So your dispatch is sent, then the page reloads, which wipes out your state. Logging in appears to work if you use localStorage instead of redux state, but I'm not sure how that's going to affect all the other state I will need to put in my app.